# How to execute two observables sequentially?

Tags: android, rx-java

How to execute two observables sequentially and overwrite one result by another in rxjava chain?

For example i have got data1 = observableFromDb and data2 = observableFromServer;

I would like to combine them in chain and overwrite data1 by data2 result.

Comment: Use `SERIAL_EXECUTOR` to execute tasks one by one. But works for Api 11 or higher

Comment: Could you clarify "overwrite"? If you want to overwrite data1, why fetch it?

Comment: @zsxwing final goal is show actual data from server (overwrite cached data in database by server's data), i feel that i can do it with such method: fetch data from database (cache) and show it to user, then fetch data from server and show actual data to user (overwrite).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what *concat* operator does - it executes sequentially given Observables - another Observable won't start until previous one gets *completed*

```
Observable.concat(dataBaseObservable, networkRequestObservable)
          .subscribe(Data -> {
              // do something with data
          });
```